# Find duplicates comparing 2 fields in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I've a table with the following data

```
id  parent_id   ascii_name  lang
1   123         Foo         en
2   123         Foo         fi
3   456         Bar         it
4   345         Foo         fr
```

I want to select all the records that have the same `parent_id` and `ascii_name`, basically I want this:

```
id  parent_id   ascii_name  lang
1   123         Foo         en
2   123         Foo         fi
```

Right now I was able to select the records having only the same `ascii_name`:

```
id  parent_id   ascii_name  lang
1   123         Foo         en
2   123         Foo         fi
4   345         Foo         fr
```

using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ascii_name in 
(SELECT ascii_name FROM table GROUP By ascii_name
 HAVING "count"(ascii_name) > 1)
```

I don't know how to put the `parent_id` into the equation.

### Update

I found the right query using both @jakub and @mucio answers:

```
SELECT * FROM geo_nodes_copy WHERE (parent_id,ascii_name) in 
(SELECT parent_id, ascii_name 
 FROM geo_nodes_copy 
 GROUP By parent_id, ascii_name 
 HAVING count (1) > 1)
```

Now, the only problem is, maybe, the query speed.

Comment: Much like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query as subquery

```
   SELECT parent_id, 
          ascii_name 
     FROM table 
 GROUP By parent_id, 
          ascii_name 
   HAVING count (1) > 1
```

This will return you all the couple `parent_id`/`ascii_name` with multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it's pg you can use a row construct:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (ascii_name,parent_id) in 
(SELECT ascii_name, parent_id FROM table GROUP By ascii_name, parent_id HAVING Count(ascii_name) > 1)
```

Comment: this will not run because you need to add `parent_id` in the _GROUP BY_ clause

Comment: @vivek yeah, that's what I used, the problem now is performance

Comment: @Fed03 [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671548/find-duplicates-comparing-2-fields-in-postgresql/29672388#29672388) can be use for better performance

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by ascii_name, parent_id) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

Under some circumstances, it might be a bit faster to use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.ascii_name = t.ascii_name and
                    t2.parent_id = t.parent_id and
                    t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

For performance, include an index on `table(ascii_name, parent_id, id)`.

Comment: the first solution doesn't work, the second yes! For the index, do you mena a combined index of the 3 columns?

Comment: @vivek . . . There was an off-by-one error in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a parentid will always share the same asciiname

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table a
WHERE a.ascii_name =
(SELECT b.ascii_name 
 FROM table b
 WHERE a.parent_id = b.parent_id)
```